# When I try to create a new project curl error appear

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

When I try to create a new project using following command

```
laravel new project_name
```

I am getting following error:

```
Crafting application...

In CurlFactory.php line 186:

  cURL error 56: Recv failure: Connection was reset (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)


new [--dev] [--force] [--] [<name>]
```

Comment: The error message is tell you why. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html, Failure with receiving network data.

Comment: @lighter yes may be this is because of the proxy issue at my office.

Answer (score 2):

With neither the resources nor the will to get into the logic responsible for this issue, faced I it and came forth victorious by using composer instead, thus;

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name
```

I hope it helps.
 See the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation).